# Enable Runtime Compilation in ASP.Net RCL Project

Tags: runtime-compilation

I have created a new Razor Class Library (.Net 5) and added it as a Project reference in another ASP.Net Core Web application . In this Web app, I added    services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation() in Startup.cs.
Now any view page changes under web application is immediately reflecting in browser without rebuilding the code. But it is not working for any views in RCL project. How can I enable runtime compilation in RCL as well?

Comment: Im was having the same issue and followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#enable-runtime-compilation-conditionally -> Enable runtime compilation for a Razor Class Library